# Add multiple popups to a single marker location coordinate

Tags: r, popup, leaflet

I have two different types of information I would like to display in a location.

I can do it like this, displaying everything in a single popup:

```
    leaflet() %>% addCircleMarkers(data  = goo,
                     lng   = ~ lng,
                     lat   = ~ lat,
                     popup = ~ paste("<strong>", str_to_title(name), "</strong>", 
                                     "<br>", "Process:", n_proc,
                                     "<br><p style=color:#808080>", process, '</p>'), 
                     clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(spiderfyDistanceMultiplier = 1.7))
```

[image]

Or I can generate two markers for the same location, displaying information separately, using a `vector` inside the `popup` argument, with the two different chunks of text in its own `paste`

```
    leaflet() %>% addCircleMarkers(data  = goo,
                     lng   = ~ lng,
                     lat   = ~ lat,
                     popup = ~ c(paste("<strong>", str_to_title(name), "</strong>", 
                                     "<br>", "Process:", n_proc),
                                     paste("<br><p style=color:#808080>", process, '</p>')), 
                     clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(spiderfyDistanceMultiplier = 1.7))
```

[image]

In the image above, each marker represents the same location, but with different popup content.

However, what I would like to do is to display two popups for a single marker. A user would clink on the marker and popups would come out, side by side (maybe in a spiderfy manner).

Is there a way to do it?